# Stacked Column chart that creates buckets

Tags: powerbi

I currently have a bar graph in `power-bi`. The graph has distinct `id's` on the `x axis` and the amount of mail they received on the `y axis`. In the Table I am using, I have `SalesYear`, `id`, and a `Val` column which has the value `1` in each row. The `id` shows up multiple times in the table, sometimes more than twice in the same year.

The problem is I want the `graph reversed`. I would like to bucket people based on how much mail they received. Then use a `slicer` to see how much they receive per year. I have been struggling to find a solution on my own, would anyone have any ideas on how to approach this. 
Table l looks like this:

```
    id    |     salesYear    | Val
    10    |         2012     |  1 
    11    |         2012     |  1 
    11    |         2013     |  1 
    10    |         2012     |  1 
    10    |         2013     |  1 
    12    |         2012     |  1 
    12    |         2012     |  1
```

So in the visualization I want to show that on the x-axis that people who received  1 piece of mail = 0, 2 pieces of mail = 2, 3 pieces of mail = 1. My question is how can i achieve this will a Stacked Column  chart. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
15k |  Y axis would be amount of people who recieved 1 piece, 2 piece, etc..
14k |   _ 
13k |  | | 
12k | _| |
11k || | |
10k ||_|_|_________________________
      1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9    <-AmountOfMailRecieved
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Starting with your sample data in Power BI.

[image: Sample Data]

**2)** Create a new calculated table that is a distinct list of years from your source table.

```
Years = DISTINCT(
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        Mail,
        "SalesYear", Mail[salesYear]
    )
)
```

[image: Year Table]

**3)** Create another calculated table that crossjoins the year table with a series of integers. Power BI might indicate the `[Value]` has an error (like it does for me in the picture below), but it works properly.

```
MailCounts = SELECTCOLUMNS(
    CROSSJOIN(Years, GENERATESERIES(1, 20)),
    "SalesYear", Years[SalesYear],
    "MailReceived", [Value]
)
```

[image: Count Table]

**4)** Add a calculated column that counts the number of IDs in the source table that match the year and mail count. For example, the first row is counting how many distinct IDs show up exactly once in the source table for the year 2012; it's 1 because only ID 11 shows up in 2012 once.

```
PersonCount = CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(Mail[id]),
    FILTER(Mail,
        Mail[salesYear] = EARLIER(MailCounts[SalesYear]) &&
        EARLIER(MailCounts[MailReceived]) = CALCULATE(
            COUNTROWS(Mail),
            FILTER(Mail, 
                Mail[salesYear] = EARLIER(Mail[salesYear]) && 
                Mail[id] = EARLIER(Mail[id])
            )
        )
    )
)
```

[image: Person Count]

**5)** Create relationships between your source table and the year table, and then between the year table and the count table. This will allow the creation of a slicer based on the year of your source table to filter the results from the count table.

[image: Relationships]

**6)** Optionally, you can hide the year field in the source and count tables. After doing that if you desire, create a chart as configured in the picture below

[image: Chart]

**7)** Create a slicer from the year table as shown in the picture below.

[image: Slicer]

And that's it. The chart should match with your expected outcome and can be filtered by year.

Comment: Wow Thanks so much! I really cannot express my appreciation for you taking the time out to answer my question. The steps were easy to follow and understand. It worked like a charm!

Comment: @Katan - No problem; it's my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be using DISTINCTCOUNT either in a measure or a column.

```
VariableName = DISTINCTCOUNT([AmountofMailReceived])
```